# Monitor Openvpn log and if it get specific alert.......then execute iptable command to ban IP

Tags: iptables, openvpn

I am looking to secure my openvpn server and to automatically ban unauthorized login attempts.  I am looking for a script that will do the following:

-Monitor /var/log/openvpnas.log

-Look for the following in the log...."Non-OpenVPN client protocol detected"

-This text is preceded by the IP and Port # of the connection attempt

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:zzzzz Non-OpenVPN client protocol detected'

xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx = IP

zzzzz = Port #

-If the text "Non-OpenVPN client protocol detected" is detected in log, then issue the following iptable command to ban the IP:

```
iptables -I INPUT -s xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -j DROP

service iptables save
```

Thanx!

Comment: I don't use it, but I think fail2ban can do what you want.

Comment: Fail2ban works with SSH....I've not scene any examples for Openvpn access attempts.